# NodeJS: Data argument must be of type string/Buffer/TypedArray/DataView, how to fix?

Tags: node.js

This Node JS code is from [this project](https://github.com/orderstack/hyperledger-fabric-v2-starter/blob/master/network/code/blockEventListener.js) which I'm trying to understand.

```
// initialize the next block to be 1
let nextBlock = 1

// check to see if there is a next block already defined
if (fs.existsSync(configPath)) {
    // read file containing the next block to read
    nextBlock = fs.readFileSync(configPath, "utf8")
} else {
    // store the next block as 0
    fs.writeFileSync(configPath, parseInt(nextBlock, 10))
}
```

I get this error message:

```
Failed to evaluate transaction: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type number (1)
```

I'm not too familiar with NodeJS, so could anyone explain to me how I can change this code to remove the error?

Comment: The PM2 process manager can crash with this error, if it is out of date. This can be fixed by updating PM2, in that case.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

So the error is saying the `data` (second argument of the fs.writeFileSync function) should be a string or a buffer...etc but instead got a number.

To resolve, convert the second argument to string as shown:

```
fs.writeFileSync(configPath, parseInt(nextBlock, 10).toString())
```

Answer (score 23):

**If data is JSON:**

**Write to file:**

```
let file_path = "./downloads/";
let file_name = "mydata.json";


let data = {
    title: "title 1",
};
fs.writeFileSync(file_path + file_name, JSON.stringify(data));
```

**Read from file:**

```
let data = fs.readFileSync(file_path + file_name);
data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data);
```