# Errors when using "npm start" (in MacOS)

Tags: npm, ember.js, node-modules, ember-cli, package.json

I have been trying for sometime already to just run "npm start" for an old app developed with EmberJs but I get several errors. I had tried the following:

1. Uninstall, cache clean, install Ember-cli
2. Remove the "node_modules" and run "npm install"
3. Updating ember-cli-babel
4. And some few others like updating / removing packages

I haven't open this project for around 3 years so I am pretty sure there are new updates that probably I need to follow but not sure what else to do after the list I just mentioned above.

I uploaded what I get when running "npm start".
Any guidance, help, or suggestion I would appreciate it! Thanks in advance!!

```
user@User-MacBook-Air app2 % npm start                         

> app@0.0.0 start /Users/user/Projects/app2
> ember serve

DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: app -> ember-clean-tmp -> ember-cli-babel
ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile v1.0.0 and above require the ember-cli-babel v6.7.1 or above. To use ember-cli-babel v5.x please downgrade ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile to v0.3.

An error occurred in the constructor for ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile at /Users/user/Projects/app2/node_modules/ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app@0.0.0 start: `ember serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the app@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2022-04-17T17_03_00_039Z-debug.log
```

Comment: is your project open source? 
According to your error, you probably need to update `ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile`?

Comment: @nullVoxPopuli I tried but I get another error like this:
-----
`DEPRECATION: ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Please upgrade to at least ember-cli-babel 6.6. Version 5.2.8 located: road-runner -> ember-clean-tmp -> ember-cli-babel
Object.fromEntries is not a function

Stack Trace and Error Report: /var/folders/ml/j8gl3f3525z0g3l2fcp526cc0000gn/T/error.dump.256bfca1392107a7b7e7f1df23f1d3c2.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app@0.0.0 start: ember serve
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! Failed at the app@0.0.0 start script.`

Comment: if fromEntries is not a function, you need tot use a newer node version

Comment: I did this indeed but the problem is that once I keep updating there are other errors showing. After updating my node version it is asked to update the node-sass which I did and other things I figured to fix. B now is another error 

`The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined`

Comment: do you have stack traces for each of these? those'll say where each problem is coming from. 

Unfortunately, JS just be like this :( 

unless you can re-create the dev-environment that the app was originally in, and prevent any newer dependencies from being installed, you're kinda forced to upgrade stuff -- is why so many people automate stuff like dependency updates

Comment: Thanks @NullVoxPopuli indeed I am trying to upgrade things but it keeps giving these same errors I posted last

Comment: Can you share the debug log it links to at the end of the error message? My first suggestion is to use a Node version that is adequate for the age of the project.

Answer (score 0):

To make your life easier and get your app going faster, I’d suggest trying to stay in the Babel 5.x world and see how few dependencies you can update to start with. So I’d probably start by heading the suggestion in the warning and downgrade

> ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile v1.0.0 and above require the
> ember-cli-babel v6.7.1 or above. To use ember-cli-babel v5.x please
> downgrade ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile to v0.3.

That may still mean you but other errors, but ideally you’d stick with the same ember, ember cli and ember data (and all associated dependencies) instead of trying to do a large and possibly time-consuming upgrade

Also, might be worth introducing a lock file (either using Yarn 1 or a Node 6 lock file if your system can run with it) so you don’t hit this issue in the future.

Comment: Hi @acorncom thanks for your suggestion, I did stay with ember-cli-babel v5.x but I keep getting this error which I am not sure what it means to be able to continue. 

`Could not start watchman
Visit https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined`

Comment: @Lady it looks like that is likely an issue somewhere in Node based on searching for your error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61879580/nodejs-data-argument-must-be-of-type-string-buffer-typedarray-dataview-how-to In your original post there was something at the very bottom that mentioned a log file. Is that still something you are seeing? If so, if you post it we may be able to help more

Comment: yes, I needed to add it somewhere else since is too long to post it here. Here is a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/lady22/x6gLkt01/3/) to see the log

Comment: Hmm, I’m not seeing anything obvious. In order to make faster progress, my suggestion would be to get into the Ember Discord, point people to this issue and ask people to help you debug it in real time. There is likely a need to do a lot of back and forth to figure your issue out. Feel free to ping me in there (same username) and if I’m around / free I’ll be happy to try to help